# are there any ways to run a client sided browser script for phone?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

I have googled a bit around about this question, but not found any questions exactly about what I wanna do, just similar. I have a feeling that the answer will be no, but thought I would ask to be 100% sure.

There is a website, that is not my own, so I don't have access to the files, but there is API.

There are no phone versions for this website yet, and I use the website quite a lot, so I would like to be able to make a client sided script working like a browser extension to edit the classes and that way just change the CSS of the page to make the design more phone friendly.

I know that normal extensios are not supported on phone, but are there any other ways around this? Using bookmarks or API? Or perhaps an app?

**What I myself use is iphone, so preferably a solution for IOS if possible**

Comment: Some chromium forks (Yandex browser mobile) support extensions on Android at least.

Comment: Firefox supports [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) on mobile. In particular, content scripts and content styles are supported just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The approach that one could use, providing that you only want to change css, is the following (I know that it could be done on android, and I would suspect that iPhone has similar capabilities):

- create a hybrid application that uses full-screen webView and loads the site in question.
- modify the application to provide your modified css file from application assets, when request for css file is issued from webview

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look further into this and see if I can get it to work c: